# What is a binary safe string?

Tags: string, redis

What is a binary safe string ?  Is it just a string with length attached in the string itself ? Why are they called binary safe then ? Not sure that I should tag redis, but read this term while reading redis doc.

Comment: It means you could use the contents of an image, for example, as a key. You are not confined to letters and digits.

Answer (score 16):

A binary safe string is one that can consist of any characters (bytes).

For example, many programming languages use the 0x00 character as an end-of-string marker, so in that sense a binary safe string is one that can consist of these.

Answer (score 8):

Redis string is a sequence of bytes. Strings in Redis are binary safe, meaning they have a known length not determined by any special terminating characters. Thus, you can store anything up to 512 megabytes in one string.

https://www.tutorialspoint.com/redis/redis_data_types.htm

Answer (score 3):

Binary safe string does not make any assumption about its length or terminating character. For example, in Redis (since you have mentioned Redis in your question), syntax for a binary safe bulk string is "$str_len\r\nbinary_safe_string\r\n". Here, the length of the string is made part of the string representation. With this, you can save anything as a string, say a JPEG image.
Refer to [Redis documentation](https://redis.io/topics/protocol) for more details.

Answer (score 2):

The definition of "binary safe string" in [Redis's documentation](https://redis.io/topics/data-types) is this.

> Redis Strings are binary safe, this means that a Redis string can contain any kind of data, for instance a JPEG image or a serialized Ruby object.

Therefore, binary security is relative to the c language string ended with the character '\0'.